# Calculate cumulative intraday measures that reset every day in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe in python consisting of the columns `date_time` consisting of date and time as a datetime object, `date` consisting of the date as a string, and a scalar measurement `t`. I want to calculate the cumulative value of `t` each day, and then reset it to zero at the beginning of the next day. Is there a simple way to do this? I am currently grouping the dataframe by `df.groupby('date')`.

Comment: Please provide example of your dataframe and desired result

Comment: I did provide a complete description.

Comment: @user3607022 you _didn't_ provide a [mcve]

Comment: I provided a short and reproducible description.

Comment: You need to provide the data you are working with so we can reproduce your data/error and give you solution based on your sample output.

Comment: There is no error to reproduce.

Comment: but there is _data_ that needs to be reproduced, have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and edit your question

Comment: It's a theoretical question, and as such there is no data available. Please avoid extended discussions in the comment section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
temp = df.groupby('date')['t'].cumsum().rename('t_cumulative')
df = df.merge(temp, on='date_time', how='outer')
```

Answer (score 1):

A cumulative sum that **resets** is equivalent to apply it **to groups** : each new group will reset the cumulative sum when it starts.

It is always easier to illustrate an answer with a [good minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['20191224', '20191224 01:00', 50, 'Merry'], 
    ['20191224', '20191224 02:30', 50, 'Christmas'],
    ['20191225', '20191225 02:00', 50, 'Merry'],
    ['20191225', '20191225 04:25', 50, 'Christmas'],
    ['20191225', '20191225 06:50', 50, ':)']],
    columns = ['date_str', 'date_time', 'quantity', 'msg'])
```

To make sure to cast 'date_time' column to actual timestamps ([all time formats in documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes))

```
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'], format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M")
```

To make sure that your dates are ordered (important as you will `cumsum`)

```
df = df.sort_values('date_time')
```

You can `groupby date_str` as they are represent your daily groups :

```
df.groupby('date_str').agg({
    'quantity': 'sum',
    'message': lambda x: x.join(' ')
})

            quantity                    msg
date_str        
20191224         100        Merry Christmas
20191225         150     Merry Christmas :)
```

In your case, what you want is to `transform` `cumsum`:

```
df['daily_cum_quantity'] = df.groupby('date_str')['quantity'].transform('cumsum')
```

Resulting in :

```
    date_str    date_time             quantity   msg        cum_quantity
0   20191224    2019-12-24 01:00:00   50         Merry      50
1   20191224    2019-12-24 02:30:00   50         Christmas  100
2   20191225    2019-12-25 02:00:00   50         Merry      50
3   20191225    2019-12-25 04:25:00   50         Christmas  100
4   20191225    2019-12-25 06:50:00   50         :)         150
```